# Visit from iPhone browser not counted

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

Does SE not count visits from your mobile browser?  I logged in from my iPhone yesterday after a few consecutive days of visits from my PC. I noticed today that SE had reset my number of consecutive visits, meaning it somehow didn't record that I visited yesterday.

I visited several pages and added [this comment](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4412/does-null-have-a-type/4414#comment-5887) sometime Saturday morning EST.  It was a bit before the maintenance window, but the comment persisted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you visit the site, are you just glancing at the homepage or are you reading through several pages of Qs and As? It doesn't record your presence on the homepage as you using the site. Otherwise, this could be a legitimate bug.

All times of visiting are logged using UTC, so you have to consider when you visit based on UTC instead of local time. Perhaps the code upstream will get updated to consider localtime, but I doubt it.

Comment: See my edits above.

Comment: ok, next question: are you aware of the fact that the SO clock is on UTC time, so weekends are weird?

Comment: If it's on a different clock wouldn't every day be weird? :) (Btw, the times I reported, like "Saturday morning" are EST.)

Comment: What I'm getting at is M-F we normally see it everyday, but very late on Friday is actually Saturday morning.

Comment: Ah, I'm not sure if that's the issue then; maybe I visited late enough on Sunday EST that it counted as Monday UTC so I technically missed Sunday UTC.  If that's the issue, perhaps SE should track your concurrent visits based on your timezone instead of UTC.

Comment: Yeah, I think that's been asked before. So long as you're on about the same time everyday, that'll do it.

Comment: Sweet.  I would add this little timezone tidbit into your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Something to do with the maintenance over the weekend?

Comment: That's not likely the case, but it could have been